# Screenshot - Paste in a MS Word file one by one - With out Manual Effort

Tags: screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot utilities for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows)

Every time I need to take a screen shot and I have to paste it in to a Msword file one by one. Is there any shortcuts or code we shall use to reduce the manual effort?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use [Gadwin PrintScreen](http://download.cnet.com/Gadwin-PrintScreen/3000-2094_4-10123018.html?tag=mncol;8)

Excellent screen capture apps aren't hard to come by, but excellent free ones are. With sophisticated features at no cost, it's hard to reach higher than Gadwin PrintScreen. An attractive, easily navigated interface opens up a customization wonderland for users to decide default settings for shortcut key associations, capture preferences, and output.
For our purposes, the clicking and dragging regions is the clear choice. Misjudge your region's dimensions and Gadwin PrintScreen lets you readjust them without having to start over, something many commercial competitors don't do. Setting the app to automatically open each screen capture in your favorite viewer or editor makes up for the program's lack of built-in image editor, still achieving a seamless screen capture experience from start to finish that grabs and delivers shots just where you want them.

OR
[M8 Free Multi Clipboard](http://download.cnet.com/M8-Free-Multi-Clipboard/3000-2384_4-10267618.html)

Clips-M8 is the simplest of all multi-clipboard and screen capture programs. Just have it running minimized and it captures everything you cut or copy from other programs. It keeps up to 500 clips. When you want to paste one back, all you have to do is restore M8 and click on the clip you want. When you move the mouse over the clips, you can see them in the viewer. If the clip is text, you see several lines and if it is a graphic, you see a thumbnail. Screenshots: To capture the entire screen press Prt Scr. To capture the active window press Alt+PrtScr. To capture an individual graphic from Internet Explorer or AOL, point to the graphic, right click and select "Copy" from the drop down list. M8 also allows you to paste your digital photos directly into the body of Outlook, Windows Mail, Mozilla and other email programs.